# Program format getting change in wing

Tags: python, formatting, indentation

if see the picture on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CP5fn_tuEDTDZoclM5M0V0cmc/edit?usp=sharing

this what my program looks when I write in sublime. But when I copy and paste the program in wing it looks like picture on the following link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CP5fn_tuEDZEd0SVktVHRMcEE/edit?usp=sharing

When write and save the file in sublime, and then try to run it in python it give me error

But when paste in wing and format the indentation and save. Then when I run in python it works fine.

I dont how to indent the program well in sublime.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the images it seem likely that the editor settings related to indenting are different in sublime and wing.

Check if any of the editors are using tabs instead of spaces when indenting the code and if they are, change the editor to use 4 x whitespace instead of a tab.

Comment: thanks it works I change 4 tabs to space in sublime and now it working fine thank you once again